# Browser: Shared Cache : chrome use separate rendering engine

Tags: google-chrome, browser, rendering

I learn that Chrome uses separate rendering engine for Each TAB. 
But If I open GMAIL in a tab and log-in to gmail and them open another tab then my login information is shared across the TABS.

So how is this Rendering Engine and Shared Cache different form each other.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify a bit, rendering is just the act of painting the HTML page onto your screen.  Communicating with a web server to get the HTML is done by a different part of the Chrome browser, which then passes the HTML to the renderer.  All of your web cookies are accessible to the part which communicates to the web server*, regardless of what tab the resulting HTML is rendered in, and the cookies are what's used for authentication. (* This assumes that you're not using any Incognito windows)